# Having trouble extracting rtmp stream in both VLC and python, can't find direct stream location

Tags: python, flash, vlc, rtmp, flowplayer

The "Smoken Tuna Bar", located in the florida keys, has a live webcam: http://www.smokintunasaloon.com/bar-cam.php

And after going through the page source, the only camera link is here: http://www.floridakeyswebcams.tv/client-cam/smokin-tuna-bar.cfm

And after going through *that* page source, I found that there's only a few lines of backend code:

```
    <!-- Flowplayer -->
    <a style="display:block;width:540px;height:304px" id="rtmpplayer">
    </a>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/flowplayerflash/flowplayer-3.2.13.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        flowplayer("rtmpplayer", "/flowplayerflash/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf", {
            clip: {
                url: 'mp4:smokintunabar.stream',
                live: true,
                provider: 'rtmp'
            },

            plugins: {

                controls: {
                    url: "/flowplayerflash/flowplayer.controls-3.2.16.swf"
                },

                rtmp: {
                    url: "/flowplayerflash/flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.13.swf",
                    netConnectionUrl: 'rtmp://wowza.floridakeysmedia.com:8090/smokintunabar/'
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

And that's where I got stuck. No matter what I do, I can't open the stream in VLC, or in python rtmp. None of the links will download or open, and the rtmp documentation:
https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/rtmp/pdf/rtmp_specification_1.0.pdf

Has been very much useless. If anyone with RTMP experience could help me, and show me where the video is *streaming from*, that would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If anyone could show me where the video is streaming from...

An `RTMP` link is made of two parts : **server** and **stream**. Combine them to make the full URL.

Here your **server** is the `netConnectionUrl` and your **stream** is the `url` which begins with `mp4: etc` (note you must actually drop the beginning "`mp4:`" part since that's just for setup purposes only).

The full URL to use in VLC player should look like :

**rtmp://wowza.floridakeysmedia.com:8090/smokintunabar/smokintunabar.stream**

Comment: Any idea how to do it in python, or should I work that out myself?